# Drop down menu going under #main div background in IE 7/8/9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Here is the link to the domain http://linenwoods.com I am working on. I am going to fit the navigation list items on the header, but when the drop down menu is implemented I'm pretty sure it'll go under the #main div like you see currently. Is there any easy way fix to this? I couldn't find anything related to this from a google search .. was hoping someone could help me out. Below is the relevant CSS .. I tried playing around with z-index with no luck as I was told IE8 renders it strangely. If you have the time please follow the link with IE and leave a response .. I am trying to be as cross-browser compatible as possible and already am at a pretty pathetic start. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
body { 
background-image:url('Background1.jpg');
background-position: center;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
opacity: 0.8;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

#main {
width : 1010px;
height: 1315px;
background-color: white;
margin-top: 15px;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

header {
width: 1010px;
height: 230px;
background-color: white;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 15px;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

footer {
width: 1010px;
height: 230px;
background-color: white;
margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this CSS (works only in IE8 and 9):

```
ul.nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2; /* 2 or higher */
}
```

IE7 does... [weird things](http://richa.avasthi.name/blogs/tepumpkin/2008/01/11/ie7-lessons-learned/) with the `z-index`. If you want to target IE7 as well, you can do this (CSS hack taken from [this page](http://paulirish.com/demo/css-hacks)):

```
ul.nav {
  position: relative;
  position: absolute !ie7; /* For IE7 only */
  z-index: 2; /* 2 or higher */
}
```

Comment: Ok great the first bit of CSS worked quite well .. and I think I'll also use the IE7 hack. Thank you so much! *edit* I forgot to ask if the IE hack will affect me when I begin the drop down menu?

Comment: Depends on how you code it. Assuming your dropdown menu is dynamically shown, using the same static implementation you have, it should be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using z-index only works on positioned elements. When you tested zindex stuff, were your elements either absolute or relative?

Comment: ah .. I forgot about that. Nope they weren't positioned .. yet. When I complete the mark-up/css for the drop down menu I'll most likely use positioning (relative/absolute) so that may work for me. Is that likely the only solution?

Comment: Probably.  I had a similar issue with status messages (<div>'s) showing up behind my nav menu.  Adding position relative fixed it for me